# how to plot a histogram by given points in python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have 60 numbers divided into 8 intervals:

```
[[534, 540.0, 3], [540.0, 546.0, 3], [546.0, 552.0, 14], [552.0, 558.0, 8], [558.0, 564.0, 14], [564.0, 570.0, 9], [570.0, 576.0, 6], [576.0, 582.0, 3]]
```

The number of numbers in each interval is divided by 6:

```
[0.5, 0.5, 2.33, 1.33, 2.33, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5]
```

How do I create a histogram so that the height of the bars corresponds to the obtained values, while signing the intervals in accordance with my intervals? The result should be something like this

[i do not have reputation to post images, so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvCCm.jpg])

Comment: Look into barplot: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html It should give you what you want after formatting your input.

Comment: I know about it, but it not what i want, becouse of intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running F Blanchet's code generates the following graph in my IPython console:

[image]

That doesn't really look like your image. I think you're looking for something more like this, where the x-ticks are *between* the bars:

[image]

This is the code I used to generate the above plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Include one more value for final x-tick.
intervals = list(range(534, 583, 6))

# Include one more bar height that == 0.
bar_height = [0.5, 0.5, 2.33, 1.33, 2.33, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0]

plt.bar(intervals,
        bar_height,
        width = [6] * 8 + [0],  # Set width of 0 bar to 0.
        align = "edge",         # Align ticks at edge of bars.
        tick_label = intervals) # Make tick labels explicit.
```

Comment: Why is there a 0 on the end and 83 instead of 82? What happens in width? I can see it doesn't work without it, but why?

Comment: @eterwo you need 583 instead of 582 because python excludes the final value passed into `range`. For example `list(range(0, 3))` returns `[0, 1, 2]` and not `[0, 1, 2, 3]` – i.e. `3` is excluded. The 0 in `bar_height` is there because `align = "edge"` aligns the ticks at the left edge of the bars, so we need one more bar so 582 can appear on its left edge. The 0 in `width` (argument in `plt.bar`) is there because there would otherwise be a gap between 582 and the edge of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplotlib` :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[534, 540.0, 3], [540.0, 546.0, 3], [546.0, 552.0, 14], [552.0, 558.0, 8], [558.0, 564.0, 14], [564.0, 570.0, 9], [570.0, 576.0, 6], [576.0, 582.0, 3]]

x = [element[0]+3 for element in data]
y = [element[2]/6 for element in data]

width = 6 
plt.bar(x, y, width, color="blue")
plt.show()
```

More documentation [here](https://plot.ly/matplotlib/bar-charts/)

Comment: Thanks, it's close, but not enough. Is it possible to get the intervals exactly as in the picture?

Comment: Yes I just corrected it with +3 in the x list to have exactly the same as the picture.

Comment: Wow, that works, but I do not understend how. Could you explain?

Comment: By default it aligns the middle of the bar with the value in x, and the width is 6 here so the interval is [x-3;x+3]. By adding 3 I add  an offset to get the interval [x;x+6] that we want.

Comment: Is there no way to get matplotlib to specify the specific intervals I gave it?

Comment: By default it aligns the middle of the bar with the value in x. I just found this trick to get the good result.